# What Jekyll instructions allow to generate next/previous topic navigation links automatically?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I am creating a GitHub pages site for the project and stuck at navigation links for next/previous topic and related topics as well. Of course I can create them manually, but it's a hell of a work.

I need something like this (scroll down to the bottom of the page, there are links to previous and next topics): [Sample GitHub page](https://dmitripopov.github.io/helpinator-github-pages/exportgithubpagesfromhelpinator)

Those links were generated by the tool named Helpinator right into the code of the topic. Are there some tags or code or whatever can automate it for me?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [raw file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DmitriPopov/helpinator-github-pages/master/docs/exportgithubpagesfromhelpinator.md) for the page that you linked, you can see the following code and use it as an example:

```
[Commit project files --&gt;](commitprojectfiles "Next")
[&lt;-- Clone repo to your PC](clonerepotoyourpc "Previous")
```

The markdown links are just pointing at relative files, which is [supported by GitHub](https://github.blog/2013-01-31-relative-links-in-markup-files/).

---

Otherwise if you're trying to link between posts in Jekyll, you can use the `page.next.url` and `page.previous.url` to get the url of the next/previous post (more info in [docs](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/#page-variables)).

```
<a href="{{ page.previous.url }}">
  <div>Previous Post</div>
</a>

<a href="{{ page.next.url }}">
  <div>Newer Post</div>
</a>
```